# Iphone OS Version 3.0.1 (7A400) - not supported by latest version of XCode

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am very new to IPhone development.  I have upgraded my IPhone to the latest version 3.0.1 (7A400).  I have also downloaded the latest version of the SDK - but the latest version of the OS that XCode supports is 3.0.1 (7A341).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Pretty easy.

```
ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \(7A341\) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1
```

**Update**: In Xcode 4, this path has changed to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/...`

Comment: if you are using 3.1 SDK, then remove the "\ \\(7A341)" part, cause the folder name is "3.0" not "3.0 (7A341)"

Comment: Perfect. I love easy solutions like this :)

Comment: I recently downgraded my 3.1b3 iPhone to 3.0.1. Running Xcode 3.1 and iPhone SDK 3.1, I get this same error. I had previously created the symlink before going to 3.1 and it helped me code on 3.0.1, but now that I went back it is broken again. I get this message: Your device is running an incompatible debugger.
Please reboot your device or re-install its software.

(0xE8000033).

Comment: @TuyenNguyen thank you, I took care of this about three years ago.

Answer (score 10):

To continue development with iPhone SDK 3.0 on your iPhone, iPhone 3G and iPhone 3GS running iPhone OS 3.0.1 will need to perform the following:

1. Log into your Mac with an Admin account and launch the Terminal application (/Applications/Utilities)
2. Copy and paste the following line into Terminal:
   ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ (7A341) /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1

Note: If you installed iPhone SDK 3.0 somewhere other than the default /Developer location, replace the "/Developer" directory as appropriate.

More information on this thread on the Apple Dev Forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/105448#105448

Answer (score 0):

I had to put quotes around the paths and also restart xcode:

ln -s "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0 (7A341)" "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1"

Answer (score 0):

ok you need to take the old 3.0 (7a341) dir and copy it into 3.0.1 (7A400)
i had three files in it i needed to copy

open up finder go to folder

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

make new folder 
3.0.1 (7A400)

copy files into it from 
3.0 (7A341)

restart xcode

done!!

Answer (score 0):

For science here is the variation I had to use :

```
sudo ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0\ \(7A312g\)/ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.0.1
```

The difference being the (7A12g) in the original filename. I just created the symlink by hand in terminal, then restarted XCode and it all fit together.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what worked was backing up my iPad, restoring it from iTunes, deleting it from my organizer, then connecting it and letting the organizer find it again.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

We had a slightly more recent manifestation of this problem.  Just adding this answer as this is the top google hit for the error message.

In XCode 4.3.3, connecting a 2nd generation iPod Touch with iOS 3.1.3, it was neccesary to create the symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.3 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.3\ \(7E18\)
```

"3.1.3 (7E18)" is the Software Version that was displayed in XCode Organiser for the iPod.

Restarts of XCode and the iPod, and installation of the correct Device Debugging Support library were also required.

Answer (score -1):

Ouch.. I too had this... ended up reinstalling SDK + Xcode... If only I posted my issue here :(

Comment: I did that too!  Then I got smart and posted the question to here... ;-)